# Human readable output in bits

Tags: python

I have looked at the modules *humanize* and *humanfriendly*, and neither can convert a large bit value to human readable bit output (e.g. Mbits, Gbits, Tbits, ..etc).  Has anyone come across such a module?  Example:

```
mbits = 1000000
gbits = 1000000000
```

Then

```
print(human.bits(mbits)) # would output "1 Mbit"
print(human.bits(gbits)) # would output "1 Gbit"
```

...etc, up to exabit.

Comment: Can you provide examples of what you are looking for?

Comment: @ScottHunter I just updated with an example.

Comment: Why not write one? Questions about that would at least be on topic (soliciting a 3rd party module is explicitly not)

Answer (score 0):

You can try `hurry.filesize`

```
>>> from hurry.filesize import size
>>> size(11000)
'10K'
```

There is another library `bitmath`

```
>>> from bitmath import *
>>> small_number = MiB(10000)
>>> print small_number.best_prefix()
9.765625 GiB
```

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't what I asked for.  I need to display human readable values in bits, not bytes.  I need to display bandwidth amounts which are in bits, not file sizes which are in bytes.  It seems every human readable module only factors bytes.

Comment: if you want to initialize a variable with value in bytes you can simply say `size = bitmath.Byte(10000)`

Comment: This is again Bytes.  I need bits.  :)

Comment: can bitmath detect the bit value vs. having to specify "MiB(10000) ?

Comment: Yes, units need to be specified for bitmath. There is parse_string function but it doesn't work unless you specify units.